# Console.log updates the state, but UI not modified using useState hook

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and I want to update the UI with react hook useState, which updates the UI with the string "Updated". However, the console.log logs  "Updated" correctly, and the UI is not modified. Where is the problem? The code is given below.

```
const ExpenseItem=(props)=>{
   const[title,setTitle] = useState(props.title)
   const clickHandler=()=>{
   setTitle("Updated")
   console.log(title)
    
}    
return(
    <div>
        
        <div className="expense-item">
           <ExpenseItemDate date={props.date}/>
        
        <div className="expense-item__description">
            <h2>{props.title}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="expense-item__price">
            ${props.amount}
        </div>
        <button onClick={clickHandler}>ClickMe</button>

        </div>

    </div>
)


};
export default ExpenseItem
```

[image]

```
{
  "name": "react-complete-guide",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

Look at the attached Image. The "Toilet Paper" should be changed to "Updated". But not updated. Can't figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing props.title, but updating title from state.

Just { title } should work.